# Suitable description for this type of sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-techniques

Lyrics from [The National's Ada](http://www.metrolyrics.com/ada-lyrics-the-national.html)

> Ada don't talk about reasons why you
>   don't want to talk about reasons why
>   you don't wanna talk

Is there a word for the structure of this sentence - for me it loops like **circular reasoning**

If I have to describe this as a __ sentence - can it be "*helical*" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rhetorical figure known as *epimone*, which is the consecutive repetition of phrases in a sentence or passage.

Comment: you've led me on to [6 more](http://grammar.about.com/od/rhetoricstyle/a/effectrepet.htm) repetitive constructs that I never heard of.